# Algorithm that generates all contiguous subarrays

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

Using the following input,

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'm trying to get the following output

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

As far I have made such an algorithm, but time complexity is not good.

```
def find(height):
    num1 = 0
    out = []
    for i in range(len(height)):
        num2 = 1
        for j in range(len(height)):
            temp = []
            for x in range(num1, num2):
                temp.append(height[x])
            num2 += 1
            if temp: out.append(temp)
        num1 += 1
    return out
```

Is there any way to speed up that algorithm?

Comment: Itertools is a good tool for this. You can read about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Take a look at itertools.product in your case

Comment: The three first answers list all sub-sequences, but your example output lists only contiguous sub-sequences. For instance, `[1,4]` is part of the output in all three answers, but is not part of your example output. Can you please clarify explicitly whether you are interested in **contiguous sub-sequences** or **all sub-sequences**?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Contiguous sub-sequences

*The OP specified in comments that they were interested in **contiguous** sub-sequences.*

All that is needed to select a contiguous sub-sequence is to select a starting index `i` and an ending index `j`. Then we can simply return the slice `l[i:j]`.

```py
def contiguous_subsequences(l):
  return [l[i:j] for i in range(0, len(l)) for j in range(i+1, len(l)+1)]

print(contiguous_subsequences([1,2,3,4]))
# [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

This function is already implemented in package more_itertools, where it is called [substrings](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.substrings):

```py
import more_itertools
print(list(more_itertools.substrings([0, 1, 2])))
# [(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

#### Non-contiguous sub-sequences

*For completeness.*

Finding the "powerset" of an iterable is an [itertool recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```py
import itertools
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

It is also in package [more_itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.powerset):

```py
import more_itertools
print(list(more_itertools.powerset([1,2,3,4])))
# [(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this using **list comprehension** in one line (`O(N^2)`), which is faster than your existing method:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [x[i:j] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(i+1,len(x)+1)] 
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

**Runtime comparison**:

```
# your solution
>>> %timeit find(x)
9.23 µs ± 445 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

#itertools method suggested by 'stef' 
>>> %timeit list(more_itertools.substrings([1, 2, 3,4]))
3.18 µs ± 20.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

#List comprehension method
>>> %timeit [x[i:j] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(i+1,len(x)+1)]
3.09 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l = len(a)
ret = []
for i in range(l):
    ll = i + 1
    while ll <= l:
        ret.append(a[i:ll])
        ll +=1
print(ret)
```

prints:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]
```

Comment: Program can not return `[1, 3]` as between 1 and 3 is 2. Same with the `[1, 4]`

Comment: clearly `[1,3]` and `[1,4]` are in the return value

Comment: In the question, there is no such an output desired by me.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I've solved this using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) [top - down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design) approach.

The time complexity here is `O(N^2)`.

I'm not sure if the time complexity for this problem could be reduce further ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

```
def find(arr):
    d = {}
    d[0] = []

    i = 1
    while (i <= len(arr)):
        d[i] = [] + d[i - 1]
        val = arr[i - 1]
        j = i - 1
        l = len(d[i - 1])
        while (j > 0):
            d[i].append(d[i - 1][l - j] + [val])
            j = j - 1

        d[i].append([val])
        i = i + 1

    return d[len(arr)]

input = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(find(input))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [1, 2], [2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4], [4]]
```